# In composite StateT / Maybe monad, how to take either possibility that succeeds?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

In Haskell, here's a monad that combines the State and Maybe monads:

```
type StatefulMaybe a = StateT Int Maybe a
```

This is a computation that can succeed (returning a value) or fail.  If it succeeds, it carries a state along with the returned value.

I'd like to write a function

```
choice :: StatefulMaybe a -> StatefulMaybe a -> StatefulMaybe a
```

that takes two such computations and returns the first one (if any) that succeeds.  Only state changes by the successful computation are carried forward.

In fact after some experimentation I figured out how to write this.  Here it is:

```
orMaybe :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
orMaybe (Just x) _ = Just x
orMaybe Nothing x = x

choice :: StatefulMaybe a -> StatefulMaybe a -> StatefulMaybe a
choice mx my = StateT (\s ->
    (runStateT mx s) `orMaybe` (runStateT my s)
  )
```

It works:

```
foo :: StatefulMaybe String
foo = do
    modify (+ 20)
    fail "didn't succeed"

baz :: StatefulMaybe String
baz = do
    modify (+ 30)
    return "two"

bar :: StatefulMaybe String
bar = do
    s <- choice foo baz
    return (s ++ " done")

> runStateT bar 0
Just ("two done",30)
```

My question is this: **Is there some easier or more natural way to write this choice function than my implementation above?** In particular, is there some way I can lift the `orMaybe` function into my monad?

Comment: `orMaybe` is `mplus` from `MonadPlus` -- I think using `mplus` instead of `choice` should work, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think that this function already exists: [<|>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-):

```
bar :: StatefulMaybe String
bar = do
    s <- foo <|> baz
    return (s ++ " done")
```

The `<|>` function is part of the `Applicative` type class, of which `StateT` is an instance when the inner monad is both a `Functor` and `MonadPlus` instance, which is true for `Maybe`.

```
*Q66992923> runStateT bar 0
Just ("two done",30)
```

As luqui suggests in the comment, I think that `mplus` ought to work, too, since the default implementation of `mplus` is `<|>`.

Comment: Fantastic.  I just knew there had to be an easier way.  :)